# Question about mongoid references_many, views and controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I'm playing with MongoDB in Rails 3 via Mongoid. I've defined the classes below, but when I attempt to create a new Hyperlink via the scaffolded view I get an error. I believe what is happening is that the `Tags` array is not being handled properly. I'm using the default controller scaffold. What do I need to do to ensure mongoid knows how to add the tags?

```
class Hyperlink
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  field :url
  embeds_many :comments

  references_many :tags

  validates_presence_of :name, :url
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :url
end

class Tag
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
  referenced_in :hyperlink    
end
```

Controller response
    TypeError in HyperlinksController#create

```
can't convert Symbol into Integer

**Request**

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"yn5SwZPBIMcpzrGQeO9t3tJ2Y2Q6nlsDBPbI43ahj0k=",
 "hyperlink"=>{"name"=>"Stack Overflow",
 "link"=>"http:://www.stackoverflow.com",
 "tags"=>{"tag"=>"programming"}},
 "commit"=>"Create Hyperlink"}
```

Comment: Please post the controller and view source here or as a gist. (Alternately, push the whole shebang to a GitHub project.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags` to `HyperLink` .

Comment: That was it! I'll award the bounty as soon as the time restriction is lifted. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that helped. I can't tell you how many times I've run into this same issue, both with ActiveRecord and Mongoid.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your parameters should look something like this(notice the change in tags):

```
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"yn5SwZPBIMcpzrGQeO9t3tJ2Y2Q6nlsDBPbI43ahj0k=",
 "hyperlink"=>{"name"=>"Stack Overflow",
 "link"=>"http:://www.stackoverflow.com",
 "tags"=>{"0" => {"name"=>"programming", :id => "xxxx"}}},
 "commit"=>"Create Hyperlink"}
```

As jdc already pointed controller and view code would be much helpful to actually point out the problem.